# Using calculations above, mark the statements below must be true.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\vec{x}, \vec{y}, \vec{z}$ be non zero vectors  and suppose $\vec{w}=-15\vec{x}-5\vec{y}+4\vec{z}.$ Suppose $\vec{z}=3 \vec{x}+\vec{y}$. Then find $\vec{w}$ in terms of $\vec{x}, \vec{y}$ and $\vec{z}$

Using calculations above, mark the statements below must be true.

- $span\{\vec{x}, \vec{y}, \vec{z} \}=span\{\vec{x}, \vec{y}, \vec{w} \}$
- $span\{ \vec{w}, \vec{z} \}=span\{\vec{y}, \vec{w} \}$
- $span\{\vec{x}, \vec{z} \}=span\{\vec{x}, \vec{z}, \vec{w} \}$
- $span\{\vec{x}, \vec{y}\}=span\{ \vec{y}, \vec{w} \}$
- $span\{\vec{x}, \vec{w}\}=span\{ \vec{z}, \vec{w} \}$

**My attempt**

$\vec{w}=-15\vec{x}-5\vec{y}+4\vec{z}=-15\vec{x}-5\vec{y}+4(3 \vec{x}+\vec{y}).$

Hence, $\vec{w}$ and $\vec{z} \in span \{\vec{x}, \vec{y}\}$

So,

- $span\{\vec{x}, \vec{y}, \vec{z} \}=span\{\vec{x}, \vec{y}, \vec{w} \}=\{\vec{x}, \vec{y}\}$
- $span\{ \vec{w}, \vec{z} \}=span\{\vec{y}, \vec{w} \}=\{\vec{x}, \vec{y}\}$
- $span\{\vec{x}, \vec{z} \}=span\{\vec{x}, \vec{z}, \vec{w} \}=\{\vec{x}, \vec{y}\}$
- $span\{\vec{x}, \vec{y}\}=span\{ \vec{y}, \vec{w} \}=\{\vec{x}, \vec{y}\}$
- $span\{\vec{x}, \vec{w}\}=span\{ \vec{z}, \vec{w} \}=\{\vec{x}, \vec{y}\}$

Hence, all the statements are true. Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to realize is that $w$ and $z$ have the same direction since $$w=-15x-5y+4z=-5(3x+y)+4z=-z$$

So $span(w,z)=span(w)\ne span(y,w)$ and $span(x,w)\ne span(w)=span(z,w)$.